# R Grep error when trying to pull a specific pattern of letters

Tags: r

I am having trouble using the grep function to pull out all passengers in this data set for those who are going to their home destination. I an searching for those destinations that contain 'MO' and then I want to report the number of passengers from 'MO' but I am getting an error.

```
csv_data <- read.csv(file = '/dsa/data/all_datasets/titanic3.csv' , header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"",
     dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "")


df1 <- data.frame(csv_data)
df1

grep('MO', df1 = home.dest)]
```

```
Error in grep("MO", df1 = home.dest): unused argument (df1 = home.dest)
Traceback:
```

Comment: Not sure but you might be looking for `grep("MO", df1$home.dest)`. This will give you the row numbers you need to subset your `df1` with.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
grep('MO', df1$home.dest) # Assuminng home.dest is the column name
```